# How to hide inner wrapper blank space using child?

Tags: css

I'm trying to program my own website, I must say that I'm very new to this. 
I've been struggling trying to hide a white space that appears to be a 30px padding of the inner wrapper. I've tried to hide it in my child theme using:

```
.body {  
height: 100%;
margin: 0}
}

html {  
height: 100%;
margin: 0}
}
```

and some other codes I've found on the internet but I think I'm not doing it properly.

It's the white space between the Instagram widget and the footer. My site is: http://thenoirportrait.com

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFOQz.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a padding there:

```
body #inner_wrapper {
  padding: 30px 0;
  position: relative;
}
```

Change it to:

```
body #inner_wrapper {
  padding: 30px 0 0;
  position: relative;
}
```